# nginx change default charset

Tags: configuration, nginx

I set  charset utf-8; at http tag, but error.log given:
2012/08/22 10:47:33 [error] 6588#1560: *1 no "charset_map" between the charsets "GB2312" and "utf-8" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index2.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"....
Any idea? I want set default language to utf-8 only.

Answer (score 1):

From the error you gave it would seem that your fastcgi-app is passing gb2312 encoded text to nginx. So either:

- make sure it's sending utf-8 text, or
- make sure you have  an appropriate charset_map set up in nginx (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_charset_module.html#charset_map)